# References for the operator $(I-\Delta)^{\alpha /2}$

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I am studying PDEs involving fractional differential operators, and I have found a few properties for the operator $(I-\Delta)^{\alpha /2}$ scattered through scientific papers. I wonder if there is a book, or a survey paper, to refer to as a general reference for this kind of operator. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried searching for Bessel potentials? I know Stein's book (Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions) has some properties, as well as Grafakos' book (Modern Fourier Analysis).

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, Stein's book is the first attempt that I made. But I am looking for a more... PDE oriented approach. For the operator $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ there are now several surveys, but it seems to me that for the (more regular) $(I-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ we have to look for lemmas in old papers.

Comment: What properties are you looking for? Schauder estimates? $L^p$? Dirichlet problem?

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, basically the linear theory on which one tries to build a nonlinear theory for equations like $(I-\Delta)^{\alpha /2}u = f(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

What about Folland's [Introduction to Partial Differential Equations](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5860.html) or Taylor's [Partial Differential Equations I](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441970541)?